# Apply function over list then iterate over second variable, in r

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to have a function apply over a list and iterate over a second variable in the function, in r.

Here is an example:

Create the data

```
A <- data.frame(var = 1:3, year = 2000:2002)
B <- data.frame(var = 4:6, year = 2000:2002)
C <- data.frame(var = 7:9, year = 2000:2002)

ABC <- list(A, B, C)

> ABC
[[1]]
  var year
1   1 2000
2   2 2001
3   3 2002

[[2]]
  var year
1   4 2000
2   5 2001
3   6 2002

[[3]]
  var year
1   7 2000
2   8 2001
3   9 2002
```

Write the function: `sum` (which simply filters for a start year and sums the 'var' values - sorry this simple function got messier in this example than I had intended).

```
library(dplyr) 

sum <- function(dat, start.year) {
  dat %>%
    filter(year >= start.year) %>%
    select(var) %>%
    colSums() %>%
    data.frame(row.names = NULL) %>%
    rename(var = '.') %>%
    mutate(start = start.year)
}
```

Now I can apply the function to the list (and `bind_rows` to get a neat output):

```
lapply(ABC, sum, 2000) %>%
  bind_rows()
  var start
1   6  2000
2  15  2000
3  24  2000
```

What I want to do however is iterate over `start.year` creating dataframes for `start.year = c(2000, 2001, 2002)`. This would ideally give:

```
  var start
1   6  2000
2  15  2000
3  24  2000
4   5  2001
5  11  2001
6  17  2001
7   3  2002
8   6  2002
9   9  2002
```

I have looked at `map2`, but that talks about using vectors of the same length. That would work in this case, but imagine my list had 4 items in it and only 3 records per list. So assume `map2` is doing something different. I also thought about a `nested for loop`. When I started writing that however I realized I would be dealing with list.append functions in r and that seemed wrong. I assume this is an easy thing to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with a nested `lapply/map`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(2000:2002, ~ map_dfr(ABC, sum, .x))
#   var start
#1   6  2000
#2  15  2000
#3  24  2000
#4   5  2001
#5  11  2001
#6  17  2001
#7   3  2002
#8   6  2002
#9   9  2002
```

Or inspired from @thelatemail's suggestion with `Map`

```
map2_dfr(rep(ABC, 3),  rep(2000:2002,each=length(ABC)), sum)
```

---

With `lapply`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(2000:2002, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(ABC, sum, x))))
#   var start
#1   6  2000
#2  15  2000
#3  24  2000
#4   5  2001
#5  11  2001
#6  17  2001
#7   3  2002
#8   6  2002
#9   9  2002
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned

```
do.call(rbind, Map(sum, ABC, start.year=rep(2000:2002,each=length(ABC))))
```

---

If the OP's function can be changed, another option is

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
map_dfr(ABC, ~ .x %>% 
                   crossing(year2 = 2000:2002) %>% 
                   filter(year >= year2) %>%
                   group_by(year2) %>% 
                   summarise(var = base::sum(var)))
```

---

Or instead of doing this in a `list`, we can bind them together with `bind_rows` then do a group by `sum` after `crossing` with the input 'years'

```
bind_rows(ABC, .id = 'grp') %>%
     group_by(grp) %>% 
     crossing(year2 = 2000:2002) %>% 
     filter(year >= year2) %>% 
     group_by(grp, year2) %>%
     summarise(var = base::sum(var))
```

Comment: I think the base version can be simplified slightly to `rbind` only once - `do.call(rbind, Map(sum, ABC, start.year=rep(2000:2002,each=length(ABC))))`

Comment: I think so - `Map(sum, ABC, start.year=rep(2000:2001,each=length(ABC)))` for instance.